# How to use MySQL SELECT WHERE IN (single tuple,) Python... when tuple length=1 it shows an error

Tags: python, mysql, tuples

I have 2 tuples a and b

```
print(a)
(1,2,3,4,5)

print(b)
(1,)
```

As you can see the second one has a single value... For the first one I use

```
query_a = 'SELECT something FROM mytable WHERE id IN {};'.format(a)
```

It works perfectly.

If I do the same for b, it doesn't work. It shows:

> Error: blah blah blah ..WHERE id IN (1,);': (1064, "You have an error
> in your SQL syntax...

I believe the error is because of the tuple comma -> (1,) How do I solve this. I tried

```
query_b = 'SELECT something FROM mytable WHERE id IN ();'.format(b)
```

but it also doesn't work. How do I fix this in one line?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `b` is a tuple, not a string? How do you create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. It works. To make it more clear the answer is:

```
query_a = 'SELECT something FROM mytable WHERE id IN {};'.format(str(a)[:-2] + str(a)[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some simple string manipulations to remove the comma.

```
'Tuple without comma: {}'.format(str(b)[:-2] + str(b)[-1])
```

This should work regardless of the tuple length.

Also as a side note, the `{}` is part of syntax for Format Strings in Python. You cannot replace that with `()` to make it to work.